# How to select a foreign key after narrowing down via Group By and Having in a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I've got a unique problem. I'm querying a replicated database table **cost_plan_breakdown**, and the replication is known to have some *duplicates* due to issues with deleting records. I'm not the Admin so I'm trying to sidestep these duplicates as efficiently as possible. The table looks like this:

| sys_id | sys_created_on | cost_plan | breakdown_start_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| axr123 | 2020-10-01 09:31:15 | Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon | 10-01-2020 |
| pqo100 | 2020-12-23 05:50:20 | Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon | 10-01-2020 |
| cji985 | 2020-10-01 09:31:15 | Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon | 11-01-2020 |
| twg795 | 2020-10-05 13:23:08 | DataPyramid CTB - Dave Dods | 10-01-2020 |
| jqr820 | 2020-09-28 16:11:54 | Revoluccion CTB - Marcus Vance | 11-01-2020 |
| vjo150 | 2021-01-13 11:10:09 | Server KTLO - Tom Smith | 10-01-2020 |

Cost Plans typically have between 1 and 12 breakdowns during their lifespan, but there should only be one breakdown per cost plan per month. **Notice** that the Outlook Cost Plan has two breakdowns within the same month (October) with differing sys_id and sys_created_on.

So by using a smaller subquery in the where clause, I'm trying to determine the following:

"Group the rows with identical month and year of breakdown_start_date, and identical cost_plan. Of the remaining rows, select the one with the MAX sys_created_on. Take the sys_id of that row and feed it to the parent query to only include these rows."

```
...rest of query above    
WHERE cpb.breakdown_type = 'requirement'    
AND cpb.sys_id IN
              (SELECT cpb2.sys_id
               FROM cost_plan_breakdown cpb2
               GROUP BY cpb2.name,
                        YEAR(cpb2.start_date_time),
                        MONTH(cpb2.start_date_time)
               HAVING MAX(cpb2.sys_created_on))
```

At this point, I'm running into the error

> cpb2.sys_id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I've previously semi-solved this by putting the MAX sys_created_on in the SELECT statement, and matching off that, but I realized that could pull in unwanted dupe records just because they match the sys_created_on of another.

I feel like the solution may be staring me in the face, but I'm stuck. Appreciate your help!

Comment: "I've got a unique problem" - I bet you haven't :)

Comment: Not totally sure how your title "select foreign key" comes into it though.

Comment: Ack you're right, Foreign Keys were relevant in a different issue I was mulling over. >_<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number` to number the duplicate rows and then exclude them. Ordering the row number by `sys_created_on desc` ensures you get the latest of each per month.

```
declare @Test table (sys_id varchar(6), sys_created_on datetime2(0), cost_plan varchar(32), breakdown_start_date date);

insert into @Test (sys_id, sys_created_on, cost_plan, breakdown_start_date)
values
('axr123', '2020-10-01 09:31:15', 'Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon', '10-01-2020'),
('pqo100', '2020-12-23 05:50:20', 'Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon', '10-01-2020'),
('cji985', '2020-10-01 09:31:15', 'Outlook KTLO - Lisa Lymon', '11-01-2020'),
('twg795', '2020-10-05 13:23:08', 'DataPyramid CTB - Dave Dods', '10-01-2020'),
('jqr820', '2020-09-28 16:11:54', 'Revoluccion CTB - Marcus Vance', '11-01-2020'),
('vjo150', '2021-01-13 11:10:09', 'Server KTLO - Tom Smith', '10-01-2020');

with cte as (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by cost_plan, datepart(year,breakdown_start_date), datepart(month,breakdown_start_date) order by sys_created_on desc) rn
    from @Test
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

As per your comments this (the CTE) is just a neat way to write a sub-query/derived table and can still be written as follows:

```
select *
from (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by cost_plan, datepart(year,breakdown_start_date), datepart(month,breakdown_start_date) order by sys_created_on desc) rn
    from @Test
) cte
where rn = 1;
```

Note: If you provide DDL+DML as shown above you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! 

So I threw the "with cte" setup at the beginning of my query, and them in my FROM clause inner joined to cte where sys_id = sys_id AND rn = 1. I was able to pluck out 43 very stubborn records as a result.

Noted regarding the DDL + DML.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm running into a new roadblock. The query's intended destination is Tableau, which only allows CTEs at the "Initial SQL" level, ending with a SELECT INTO. They have the CTE create a temp table, but I lack Database write access, so I'm pulling errors messages. Any alternative idea?

Comment: Okay, please ignore the above, I was able to accomplish it within the FROM clause without involving CTE. Just moved the guts to FROM as an aliased table.